# Python - tkinter - tree - database questions

Tags: python, database, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

I have a database with a customers table with the fields(id, name,surname, DOB). 
I have created a treeview which displays name and surname but soon as i try to insert the DOB in to the treeview i get an error Column index 3 out of bounds.
Also please can you explain how treeview actually works as i have copied the code from a tutorial and adapted it but still dont fully understand it.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    import sqlite3
    import os.path

   class Product:
db_name = 'database.db'

def __init__(self, wind):
    self.wind = wind
    self.wind.title('IT Products')

    frame = LabelFrame (self.wind, text = 'Add new record')
    frame.grid (row = 0, column = 1)

    Label (frame, text = 'Name: ').grid (row = 1, column = 1)
    self.name = Entry (frame)
    self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    Label (frame, text = 'Surname: ').grid (row = 2, column = 1)
    self.price = Entry (frame)
    self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


    ttk.Button (frame, text= 'Add record', command = self.adding).grid (row = 3, column =2 )
    self.message = Label (text = '',fg = 'red')
    self.message.grid (row = 3, column = 0)




    self.tree = ttk.Treeview (height = 10, colum = 2)
    self.tree.grid(row = 100, column = 0, columnspan = 100)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Name', anchor = W)
    self.tree.heading(2, text = 'Surname', anchor = W)
    self.tree.heading(3, text = 'DOB', anchor = W)
    self.tree.heading(3, text = "column B")


    ttk.Button (text = 'Delete record', command = self.deleting).grid (row = 10, column = 5)
    ttk.Button (text = 'Edit record').grid (row = 10, column = 1)

    self.viewing_records()


def run_query (self, query, parameters = ()): 


    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return query_result


def viewing_records(self):
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete (element)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM customers '
    db_rows = self.run_query (query)
    for row in db_rows:
    ##           self.tree.insert('', 2, text=str(), values=(row[1], row[2], 
    row[3]))

       self.tree.insert ('', 2, text = row[1], values=(row[1], row[2], row[3]))

def validation(self):
   return len (self.name.get()) != 0 and len (self.price.get()) != 0

def adding (self):

    if self.validation ():
        query = 'INSERT INTO customersVALUES (NULL, ?, ?)'
        parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get())
        self.run_query (query, parameters)
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format (self.name.get())
        self.name.delete (0, END)
        self.price.delete (0,END)
    else:
        self.message['text'] = 'Name field or price is empty'
        self.viewing_records()


def deleting (self):
    self.message ['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection()) [ 'values'] [0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.message[text] = 'Please select record'
        return
    self. message['text'] = ''
    name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    query = 'DELETE FROM customers WHERE name = ?'
    self.run_query(query, (name,))
    self.message['text'] = 'Record {} deleted'.format(name)
    self.viewing_records()





    if __name__ == '__main__':
         wind = Tk()
         application = Product (wind)
         wind.mainloop()
```

Comment: You misspell "column", self.tree = ttk.Treeview (height = 10, colum = 2), and have specified a treeview with 2 columns so the error message is correct. Finally, we have no idea what "but still dont fully understand it" means.  What have you tried to do to figure it out and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid column index error, provide a list of column identifiers as show below:

```
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("lname", "sex", "sdate", "dob"))
    self.tree.grid(row=100, column=0, columnspan=100)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='First Name', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("lname", text='Last Name', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("sex", text='Gender', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("sdate", text='Start Date', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading("dob", text='Birth Date', anchor=W)
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaks for your help. Has sort of worked but i am getting an extra column which is blank.                                                                  
tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("Id ", "name", "Surname", "DOB"))
tree.grid(row=100, column=0, columnspan=100)
tree.heading('#0', text='ID', anchor=W)
tree.heading("#1", text='name', anchor=W)
tree.heading("#2", text='Surname', anchor=W)
tree.heading("#3", text='DOB', anchor=W)

Comment: The extra column is due to 'Id ' in columns=("Id ", "name", "Surname", "DOB"). Please change it to columns=("name", "Surname", "DOB").